# How to implement Picture-In-Picture (PiP) in Electron

Tags: electron, picture-in-picture

In Chrome, right-clicking a video element brings up a context menu with a "Picture In Picture" option.  In Electron, right-clicking does nothing.  How can we implement Picture In Picture in Electron?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enable the `controls`-prop of the underlying `<video>` element:

```html
<video id="video" controls>
  <source src="flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO')[0].requestPictureInPicture()
```

For a full description the currently available API, see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/watch-video-using-picture-in-picture/